# dependent axios post from api call to another

Tags: reactjs

First, I POST the parent object and its ID comes back from the server. I need to then include that ID while POSTing the another post call .i am having difficulty in chaining the multiple api call.i having difficulty managing then and catch in react axios post?

**code***

parent

var hold

```
axios.post(/,data)
 .then((res) => {
        hold=res.data.msg
   .then(axios.post(/${hold},data1))
        .catch((err) => {
            toast.error("Error aayo add vayena");
          });
       })
 .catch((err) => {
    toast.error("Error cannot post");
    });
```

Comment: I think if you're only fetching data from server than use async/await or callback function. if you're doing some insert/update/delete then better do it in single post request.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `async/await` syntax for handling chained promises, since it helps for handling them in a easier way, according to this [article](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/handling-nested-promises-using-asyncawait-in-react). However, you have to use this in an `async` function.

In your case, it could be something like this:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  try{
    await axios.post(/,data).then(res => hold = res.data.msg)
  }catch(err) {
    console.log("Error cannot post");
  }
  try{
   await axios.post(/${hold},data1)
  }catch(err) {
   console.log("Error aayo add vayena");
  }
}
```

This way, the second post will be done once the first one is finished

Comment: what if second post couldn"t be done or got error while posting, then how to handle the first post ... what i mean if second post fail then first post should be also fail..

Comment: Oh yes, then you could nest the try catch, but then it comes back to what you had, so I guess it is not needed. But what is your issue here?